# No data when linking Google Analytics to Google Play

Tags: google-analytics, google-play

I have linked my Analytics account to my Play account (both belonging to the same Google account) to see how users of my app discover them via the Play Store: I already have an Analytics property that tracks in-app engagement and I linked it by following the [straight-forward documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2956981).

But even after some days have passed I do not see any Play-related data in Analytics or any additional stats in Google Play.

Do I miss something or how can I further debug this issue?

In the "Product Linking" tab of my Analytics property it says "Google Play – Actively linked. Sending and receiving data." but it really isn't.
I also tried creating a complete new property and link it but that didn't work either (so I unlinked and deleted it).

Comment: did you setup the property as an app or a web property? In general you can track anything in either but the standard reports will be missing. If you did set it up on an app account then it should be affecting a report at acquisition -> Sources -> google play. You could also look in query explorer at source related dimensions.

Comment: @lossleader and florian please help me i am unable to link google play with analytics. when i go on sorces -> google play it will showing me "This report requires that you link your apps with Google Play."